# How to get value in URL Using php

Tags: php, url

I am working on a website on which user can see the menu items of a particular Restaurant.

Every Restaurant Contains a unique ID and name

```
Example : Name -> Taj

          Id   -> 1111
```

Now what user want to do is along with the website link **(ex: www.abc.com)** he want give the **id** or **name** of any particular restaurant exactly in the below format

```
www.abc.com/1111 or www.abc.com/Taj
```

Then based on that **ID** or **Name** we want to display the menu items.

If the user is giving the value in the below format

```
www.abc.com/value=1111 or www.abc.com/value=Taj
```

then we can use the **GET** Method as below.

```
$value=$_GET['value'];

Code for Printing the menus come here..!!
```

But the Client requirement is like **www.abc.com/1111**

So if the user give like that the server will check for **1111 folder** or **Taj Folder**. we will get the error **File Not Found**.

Anyone have the solution for this please Suggest me.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `.htaccess` like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /?value=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Please clarify me on more thing after doing that how can we get the value . I mean where to write the code. In index.php or where..?

Comment: In `index.php`, you should access `$_GET['value']`.

Comment: I have added the code in ht access file and uploaded into server. My path is like `www.abc.com/resturents`. All the files of project is in that folder `restuarents`. So i have uploaded there. Now if am giving like www.abc.com/resturents/1111 then it is displaying the content of  root folder files means (www.abc.com). Why it is happening like that

Comment: Because it was my understanding you were in the root folder. Try removing the slash before the `?` (so just `?value=$1`) - I'm not sure if it'll work or not, but it's something to try first!

Answer (score 1):

you need to add re-write rule to rewrite the 
add this rule in .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule /(.*) /?value=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Apache:

- Map `/` onto your script with `Alias`
- Examine `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`

e.g.

```
Alias / /home/site/myphp.php/
```

and

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
```